# How to expand the snippet with only part of the trigger?

Tags: vim, ultisnips

I have vim with UltiSnips and it's working but only if I write the whole trigger. Is there a way to expand the snippet writing only a part of the trigger? I used to work with SnipMate and that works.

e.g.: If I have a trigger like follows:

```
snippet someTrigger
blah blah
endsnippet
```

It expand the snippet when I type:

```
someTrigger<tab>
```

But it doesn't when I type

```
some<tab>
```

Comment: What about simply shortening the triggers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultisnips also offers an API usually mapped to `<C-Tab>` `UltiSnips#ListSnippets()`, you should use that in case you want to avoid typing the entire snippet name, although the chances of clashes will be more.

Comment: This is more like what snipMate does but I can't make it work. This is what I have in my .vimrc: let g:UltiSnipsListSnippets="<c-tab>"

Comment: @AlejandroDeGregorio note that depending on your terminal `<C-Tab>` might not be recognized (it should be when using the GUI). Can you try to map it to another key and see if it works?

Comment: @skeept: Thanks, that was the problem. Now that I see how it shows the list it's not what I expected but it works.

Comment: @AlejandroDeGregorio you should try the second approach I suggest in my answer. I think the interface when you use unite plugin in nicer than the default list.

Answer (score 2):

I will offer two examples right of the documentation of ultisnips (I am familiar with these because I wrote these particular examples myself).

First one, doesn't depend on any external plugins:

```
function! ExpandPossibleShorterSnippet()
  if len(UltiSnips#SnippetsInCurrentScope()) == 1 "only one candidate...
    let curr_key = keys(UltiSnips#SnippetsInCurrentScope())[0]
    normal diw
    exe "normal a" . curr_key
    exe "normal a "
    return 1
  endif
  return 0
endfunction
inoremap <silent> <C-L> <C-R>=(ExpandPossibleShorterSnippet() == 0? '': UltiSnips#ExpandSnippet())<CR>
```

this will make `<CTRL-L>` expand current snippet if there is no other snippet matching what you already wrote.

Second example uses another plugin, `unite`:

```
function! UltiSnipsCallUnite()
  Unite -start-insert -winheight=100 -immediately -no-empty ultisnips
  return ''
endfunction

inoremap <silent> <F12> <C-R>=(pumvisible()? "\<LT>C-E>":"")<CR><C-R>=UltiSnipsCallUnite()<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <F12> a<C-R>=(pumvisible()? "\<LT>C-E>":"")<CR><C-R>=UltiSnipsCallUnite()<CR>
```

If there is only one matching snippet it will work fine. If two snippets are present then a menu appears which gives you the option to choose from one of the matching options.

Comment: This is ok if the text only match one snippet.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just interested in matching either `some` or `someTrigger`, the simplest solution is probably to use a regex trigger:

```
snippet "some(Trigger)?" !r
blah blah
endsnippet
```

The !r identifies the trigger as a regex - note that a regex trigger must be enclosed in quotes.
This will expand from either 'some' or 'someTrigger'.

See `:help UltiSnips-adding-snippets`

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I know it's not obvious from my question but I also want to match multiple triggers like someTrigger and someOtherTrigger. SnipMate shows a list of options just like the vim's omni-complete feature when that happen. I'm back using SnipMate now but I'll try UltiSnips again with more time to dig in.